# ngf-select is not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**AngularJS 1.6.9**

I have a simple file upload on JSFiddle, not sure why **ngf-select** event is not triggering while other things seems working, and no console errors.

https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/nbo3wkr7/

```
<div  ng-app="ngApp" ng-controller="ngController">

  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  
  <h3>
    {{title2}}
  </h3>
  
  <h6>
    {{title3}}
  </h6>


  <input class="pull-right" type="file" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-select="$scope.uploadFile($file, $invalidFiles)" ngf-pattern="'*zip*'" />


</div>
```

---

```
var ngApp = angular.module("ngApp", []);

ngApp.controller('ngController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'File Upload via AngularJS';
  $scope.title2 = 'Accepted File Type : *zip* only';
  $scope.title3 = 'Need to make a POST after';


  $scope.uploadFile = function(file, invalidFiles) {
    console.log(file.name, file.size, file.type);
  };
}]);
```

> ***$scope.uploadFile()*** never get to executed

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
ngf-select="uploadFile($file, $invalidFiles)"
```

instead of

```
ngf-select="$scope.uploadFile($file, $invalidFiles)"
```